# How can I access web site with ESP8266?

Tags: http, esp8266

I'm trying to retrieve a HTTP resource (`http://srcafe21.cafe24.com/mylight.php?id=2`) using ESP8266:

```
ESP8266 AT commands : 
AT+CWMODE=3
AT+RST
AT+CWJAP="iptime-3","20030214"
AT+CIFSR
AT+CIPMUX=0
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","srcafe21.cafe24.com",80
AT+CIPSEND=60
GET/HTTP/1.1
Host:srcafe21.cafe24.com/mylight.php?id=2
AT+CIPCLOSE
```

I get this response:

> ```
> SEND OK  +IPD,311:HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request 
> Server: nginx Date: ....
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of HTTP is wrong. It should be

```
GET /mylight.php?id=2 HTTP/1.1
Host: srcafe21.cafe24.com
```

Comment: Please consider to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so Stack Overflow can mark this as answered.